# Reproducing load from access-log with respect to timestamp differences (Jmeter or similar)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

**Context**

I am using JMeter with JMeter-plugins for load testing. So far I was either modelling the traffic myself (ramp-up periods, bursts, etc.) or just doing full load testing. Now, however, I need to reproduce the exact same traffic as was in the access log, so for example if I had three requests at, say, 13:00:01, 13:00:03 and 13:00:06, I will need the sampler to hit those respective requests in same timing, second one being 2 seconds after the first, and third one being 3 seconds after the second.

I surfed the web for solutions, however the only hint I got was to write custom LogParser to extract timestamps and time differences. However that doesn't cover the actual timing at which the sample will send the request, since this is stored in ThreadGroup.

**Summary**

This leads me to my question : how can I reproduce the same exact traffic (with respect to time differences between requests) as was in the access log? I don't want to model a similar one (like Gaussian etc.), I need an exact copy of traffic.

If it's impossible in JMeter, please direct me to the right tool.

Comment: Tried [Access Log Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) already?

Comment: According to the specification you provided, "The current implementation of the parser only looks at the text within the quotes [...] ", which is request's URL. It ignores timestamps, which means it also ignores time differences between requests in the access log I provide. In my experience, ALS just provides request URLs, and their timing depends on Timers or Thread Group's ramp-up, initial delay and other parameters. Again, I need something that takes those time differences into account, not just URLs.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own implementation of TCLogParser and added blocks of code borrowed from their Timers implementation to add wait. Calculating time diffs were quite easy to do. In general the only way to do it is to write your own parser.

Comment: If you are open to use other performance test platform, you may want to talk a look NetGend,  this blog http://perftestingng.blogspot.com/2014/03/replay-server-log-while-observing.html  shows that one can replay server log while observing timestamp of the logs.